# File protocol with Windows system path variables

Tags: windows, path, path-variables, file-uri, system-paths

I want to know if there is any way to use Windows system path variables with the file protocol.

Examples:

```
file:///%WINDIR%\System32\calc.exe
file:///C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop
```

The above examples will not work, so I need something similar.

Thanks.

P.S.: The above examples work in Windows Explorer, but don't work in browsers like Chrome.